# Writing an algorithm in pseudo code

Tags: pseudocode

I am trying to write an algorithm in pseudocode form to find a number in a list of numbers but I couldn't get it.

how do I rite an algorithm in pseudocode to find the smallest even number in a list of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

If you post your homework in Stack Overflow, you won't learn how to do it.

```
Var Answer
For each item in the list
  Is this item even?
    Yes:  Is Answer blank?
            Yes:  Answer = Current Item
     No:   Is Current Item < Answer?
            Yes:  Answer = Current Item
Go to next Item
Print Answer
```